# Checking if an entered number is higher or lower (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

i'm doing a highschool course, and i've been given a task to create a C# Windows Form Application, where a random number is generated upon form load, and then the user has 7 attempts to guess the number. the random number will always be between 1 and 100 (including them). the user will enter their guess into a textbox (txtGuess) and then press a button (btnGuess) to confirm their guess. after each guess, the user is told if the number is higher or lower than the number they entered. my code has not errors that Visual Studio 2010 is picking up on, but when i test it and enter a number, nothing happens.

(i also have a label that gives the user a count of how many guesses they've had, and that doesn't change either.)

here's my code, any tips for why it isn't working would be great :)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int guess, num, attempts;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        num = random.Next(100);
        txtGuess.MaxLength = 3;
    }

    private void btnGuess_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar != '\b')      //allows backspace key
        {
            e.Handled = !char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar);      //allows just number keys
        }
    }

    private void loop()
    {
        guess = int.Parse(txtGuess.Text);
        if (guess > num)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The number is lower.");
        }
        else if (guess < num)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The number is higher.");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Good job, you did it!");
            btnGuess.Enabled = false;
        }
        attempts += 1;
        lblAttempts.Text = Convert.ToString(attempts);
    }


    private void btnRestart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Restart();
    }

    private void btnGuess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            loop();
            if (attempts == 7)
            {
                btnGuess.Enabled = false;
                MessageBox.Show("7 attempts have already being made. Better luck next time!");
            }
            txtGuess.Focus();
        }
    }

    private void btnInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The aim of the game is to correctly guess the randomly generated number in 7 or less tries. The number will always be between, and including 1 to 100. Enter your guess into the text box and hit Guess! you will then be told if the number you entered is higher or lower than the random one. Press the reset button to clear your guess counter and generate a new number.                                                                                                                                                                                                     Have Fun!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it matter what number you enter? Does nothing at all ever result from your code?

Comment: no matter what number I enter, nothing ever happens.

Comment: Use breakpoints and walkthrough your code. It will let you know what is happening and where.

Comment: what happens if the number is `=` then what do you do.. do you need to change your comparison to include `>= || <=` somewhere.. if nothing is happening.. please tell us what line the `Nothing is happening` is happening at.. have you used the debugger to step through the code..

Comment: I'm embarrassed to admit this, but I have no idea what breakpoints are.

Comment: Also, make sure your button and text box events are linked correctly in the form designer.

Comment: you are coding using IDE and you don't know how to debug as well as set breakpoints.. please ask your instructor to introduce you to that and or do a youtube search on how to set break points as well as use the debugger in visual studio

Comment: Make sure you have the btnGuess Click() event correctly wired up.  Select the button.  Then in the Properties Pane (bottom right of the screen by default) click on the "Lightning Bolt" Icon.  Find the Click entry, click on the dropdown arrow to the right, and change it to your btnGuess_Click() method.

Comment: if you want a number between 1 and 100 (including) you must place this in your code: `num = random.Next(1, 101);`. At this moment 100 are never chosen and 0 sometimes.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, Luis, I've fixed that up